# Is there a way to completely reset / regenerate Quick Look preferences (system-wide)?

Tags: macos, quicklook

Quick Look fails to work on many file types that actually have Quick Look plugins and I fear that some file clobbering has occurred during my last two OS upgrades.

When Quick Look fails, the Quick Look preview is a blank page with:

`foo<TITLE></HEAD...`.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the CLI

`qlmanage -r` will reset the Quick Look cache.

Comment: What if this commend doesn't do anything, and can be run for hours without it doing anything?