# QuickLook stopped working

Tags: quicklook

What might cause quicklook to 'freeze', as it were.

quicklook has gone south to some degree, some files are QL-able, other not, 
and we're speaking of the apple plug-in type (pdfs, txt, jpg, etc.)

Even whilst running the Topher 'fix', terminal hangs 
after either the qlmanage -r or qlmanage -r cache.

Cheers, and thanks in advance for any light 
your available time might hereby shed. :)

Running OSX, ver 10.6.6 on an iMac

Comment: [Is there a way to completely reset / regenerate QuickLook preferences (system-wide)?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53818/8546) has an accepted answer that might help.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that some QL plugins are broken, you should check

```
~/Library/QuickLook/
/Library/QuickLook/
/System/Library/QuickLook/
```

for new QL plugins (check the date of the files). Maybe a program installed a new (broken) plugin? But some QL plugins are not inside the Library/QuickLook/ folders you can use

```
qlmanage -m
```

to list all QL plugins, with

```
qlmanage -m | grep -v com.apple
```

you see only plugins which are **not** from Apple.